# Edit content in BeautifulSoup ResultSet

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

My goal in the end is to add up the number within the BeautifulSoup ResultSet down here:

```
[<span class="u">1,677</span>, <span class="u">114</span>, <span class="u">15</span>]

<class 'BeautifulSoup.ResultSet'>
```

Therefore, end up with:
sum = 1806

But it seems like the usual techniques for iterating through a list do not work here.
In the end I know that I have to extract the numbers, delete the commas, and then add them up. But I am kinda stuck, especially with extracting the numbers.

Would really appreciate some help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the usual iterating techniques are working for me. Here is my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# or `from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup` if you are using BeautifulSoup 3

text = "<html><head><title>Test</title></head><body><span>1</span><span>2</span></body></html>"
soup = BeautifulSoup(text)
spans = soup.findAll('span')
total = sum(int(span.string) for span in spans)
print(total)
# 3
```

What have you tried? Do you have any error message we might be able to work with?